# PHP Filter Array While Maintaining Order of Equal Comparisons

Tags: php, sorting, usort

I have an array of objects where I need to sort by last_name. Some of the last_name fields are empty and where they're empty, they should remain in the same order but pushed to the top of the array.

What happens though is all the results with empty values are returned next to each other but in a different order.

I solved this by filtering out the items with empty values first, then sorting the remaining items, then merging them back together.

I'm wondering though if there's a better way?

```php
$emptySortValues = array_values(array_filter($condensedRoResults, function ($roResult) {
    return empty($roResult['last_name']);
}));

$notEmptySortValues = array_values(array_filter($condensedRoResults, function ($roResult) {
    return ! empty($roResult['last_name']);
}));

usort($notEmptySortValues, function ($a, $b) {
    return strcmp($a['last_name'], $b['last_name']);
});

$condensedRoResults = array_merge($emptySortValues, $notEmptySortValues);
```

I found this RFC proposal which explains a bit better what I'm wanting to accomplish. https://wiki.php.net/rfc/stable_sorting